# Credentials accessing Outlook Web Service from .net web application

Tags: .net, outlook

From within a .net web application deployed on an intranet with:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

in the web.config, I need to be able to let a user enter a date and time and an email address and have the date and time added as an appointment to the calendar for the email address.

To get things started I thought I'd try and access a mailbox and get the subjects of 10 messages:

```
ExchangeService myService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

myService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("jsmith", "mypassword");

myService.AutodiscoverUrl("fred.bloggs@mycompany.com");

FindItemsResults<Item> myResults = myService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
```

Which kind of works. I am getting a list back of 10 email subjects - but, regardless of whose email address I put in as the parameter of the AutodiscoverUrl method - the 10 subjects of MY last 10 emails are always returned. How can I access Fred Bloggs emails and, when I have acheived this, access his calendar (which is what I actually need to do) and enter an appointment? Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to add some exchange tag (e.g. exchangewebservices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An email you give as parameter to `myService.AutodiscoverUrl` is used only to find service. So for all emails you probably get the same service for all emails from the same domain. To access other users Inbox you need to go to their folder (if you have proper rights).

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId _cal = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("fred.bloggs@mycompany.com"));
Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(myService,  _cal);
FindItemsResults<Item> myResults = rootfolder.FindItems(new ItemView(10));
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure whether it works it is adapted from reading a calendar folder without actually running it.